# Excel 2016 Remove Duplicates not functioning correctly

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

I have an Excel sheet with 73,298 rows of data. When I use the remove duplicates function (RD), it will remove some of the duplicates but not others. If I find one of the remaining duplicates and select just those two lines and then run RD again, it will remove one of the two selected lines.

Also, if I run the RD function on the whole dataset, it will tell me it has removed 1,825 duplicates. If I run it again, Excel will tell me it has removed 1,825 duplicates. This is the same each time I run it but Excel cannot be removing 1,825 duplicates each time.

I have never come across this before and it is a little worrying as now it is calling into question the reliability of all of the other Excel functions.

If one of my colleagues tries this on his Excel, it works fine, removing significantly more duplicates than 1,825

Comment: I tested it my environment RD feature works correctly, how did you select columns to delete data? Did you have several columns?

Comment: @Lee Just a single column, no other data in the entire sheet. I tried it with only cell A1 selected, the whole dataset selected and the whole of column A selected. Same results.